# Do I need to power off the Arduino board before doing something?

Tags: power

Is it safe to build a circuit while the Arduino board is powered?

Should I power the board only when I have to upload the program?

Comment: which switch are you talking about?

Comment: Don't be like me, but I keep my Arduino (made in china) connected via USB to my laptop when prototyping. Many times I short pins to ground accidentally, but fortunately my laptop has builtin overcurrent protection on USBs to 500mA. If it didn't the ports (or arduino pins) would be fried long time ago. To break the board all it takes is to connect arduino pin physically to ground, and then accidentally in code assign it as output (instead of input) and set to 5V.

Comment: @FilipFranik Even if Arduino boards are inexpensive (like the clone you mention sourced from China), it's no excuse for poor practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not safe, as you may accidentally connect some points, which should not be connected and destroy Arduino and/or any other part of circuit. typically legs of resistors/LEDs tends to touch other legs near them, when you are putting it in - and if it is powered, magical smoke can happened easily.

Even if you do not this kind of mistake, not everything can be put in random order without risc of damage.

So everytime you change something with circuit, disconnect power source/USB first. And if you have big capacitors anywhere, you better make sure, they are discharged too.

You switch on the board, when the building is done and you want to program it, or use the already present program.

Answer (score 1):

It can be dangerous, not only to the Arduino, but to whatever you are connecting, if you do so with the power applied.

Current can end up flowing where it shouldn't, and components can become damaged.

However if it's something as simple as an LED then it really doesn't matter.